# Mongodb aggregation: $project works, but returns error when $group added after it

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a field appVersion which varies in length, for example:
1a
1.1a
1.1b
1b
1.1c
1.12c
2.0c
etc.

I want to group the values by the letters. in the case above its:
a:2
b:2
c:3

I'm using aggregate with the following code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project:{"_id":1,
               "app_type":{
                   $substr:['$appVersion',{ $subtract: [ { $strLenCP: '$appUser.profile.appVersion' }, 1 ] },-1]
               }
         }
    },
    
    {
    $group:{
        '_id':'$app_type',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
    }
    
])
```

the $project part alone works and gives me the letters.

the $group part alone works too (if I don't use the project)

but in the same pipeline I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$strLenCP requires a string argument, found: missing",
    "code" : 34471,
    "codeName" : "Location34471"
} : aggregate failed
```

If I remove the `$strLenCP` and write some number it works fine, but obviously doesn't give me the right result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add some sample documents in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your `appVersion` field is not embedded, you can directly provide it to `$strLenCP` as you did with the `$substr` operator like

```
$strLenCP: "$appVersion"
```

Here is the [working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3aFblzEBLeN)

Comment: The comment is correct but it doesn't work with the field "$appVersion" as well.